# PHPExcel import file from url

Tags: import, phpexcel

i would like to import .tsv file with phpexcel from a website. With locale file is working, but if i change file location on "http://...", don't working.

```
$inputFileType = 'CSV';
$data = 'http://www.domain.com/file.tsv';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setDelimiter("\t");
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPExcel uses file_exists() to test the file before opening it. file_exists() requires stat() support, which is available for a limited subset of stream wrappers such as file:// ftp:// and ssh2.sftp but is not available for http://

You'll need to pull the file to the server's local filesystem first.

Comment: How can I pull the file to server from URL? Can you please share the piece of code? Thanks

Comment: Use file_get_contents() or curl