# php retrieve xls from url to csv

Tags: php, csv, xls

I would like to use php to retrieve an xls file that's hosted on a site. Once I get the file, I would like to convert to json/csv/tsv and save it on my webserver.

I found the PHPExcel library, but all the examples i've seen have to do with local files.

```
<?php

require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$url = "http://www.website-example.com/dir/file.xls";
//Usage:
convertXLStoCSV($url,'output.csv');

function convertXLStoCSV($infile,$outfile)
{

    $fileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($infile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

    echo $infile;

    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($infile);    

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->save($outfile);
    echo $outfile;
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Nobody here is going to write this *for* you (not for free, at least).

Comment: Have you tried searching StackOverflow? I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127289/phpexcel-import-file-from-url) after 6 seconds of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely need to download a copy of the XLS file to your server, and then use PHP to parse it.

Use cURL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the XLS file contents:

```
<?php
    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "somedomain.com/some-xls-file.xls");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $xlsData= curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Then either pipe `$xlsData` to PHPExcel directly, or save the XLS file to your server using fwrite (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php):

```
<?php
    $file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/your-new-xls-file.xls", "w");
    echo fwrite($file, $xlsData);
    fclose($file);
?>
```